# Teamcity - do not run dependent configuration if none exists

Tags: teamcity

How can I restrict automatically running dependent build configurations?

I have a pipeline:

- Build
- Stage
- Release

Those are different configurations chained using snapshot dependencies. However, by default when a Teamcity configuration is run, it checks all the snapshot dependencies and then re-builds those which are not suitable.

Instead, for example, I want the `Stage` configuration to *fail* when no suitable `Build` snapshot dependency is found. (i.e. it should be impossible to run the `Stage` build without there first being a `Build` ready).

All I can find in Teamcity is configuration about how to handle situations where the dependency build *fails*, which is not what I need.

Thanks

Comment: If Build fails, do you want Stage to _fail_ or just to not start?  Is this solvable by selecting the 'Trigger after successful build only' in the Finished Build Trigger?

Comment: If Build fails, I want the Stage not to be possible to be run at all. Which can be done (I think) by what Didier Aupest suggested below. Triggering the build will be done manually, by a responsible person.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a new Snapshot dependency, inside the options you have a dropdownlist for "On failed dependency"
Default value is: `Run build, but add problem`
Instead, you can set: `Make build failed to start`, or `Cancel build`

Comment: That does not seem to be working for me. I created two configurations, `A` and `B`. `B` has a snapshot dependency on `A` with the suggested setting. When I run `B`, `A` is still automatically triggered.

Comment: I have this problem as well. This setting is on Make build failed to start, but it still triggers the dependency. It looks to me like there's no way to do what @MartinMelka wants to do.